# The relative xpath for the 2nd button of two identical buttons - selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, uiautomation

[image]

i need to identify the relative xpath for the 2nd button highlighted in the image

Can someone help me

//*[contains(@class,'fa fa-clock-o')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m56kO.png)

I used this. It identifies the first button again.

Comment: Do you have website link ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input group">
  <input id="end_time"></input>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
    </button>
  <span>
</div>
```

You would want to use the following selector for the button (not the icon in the button, because the button has the click/event handler):

`//input[@id='end_time']/following-sibling::span/button`

Which reads something like: "//" starting anywhere on the page, find an "input" whose "id" is "end_time", then get the "following-sibling" element that is a "span", and then finally the "button" under that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the professional software [testing companies](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company) keep scope of their automation frameworks enough high to handle different types of such scenarios through wide variety of reusable locators and libraries.
In this case, you can use 'Parent-Child relationship' concept in which, although your child xpaths(as mentioned) are same but as shown in DOM structure, parent xpaths are different.
Hence, you can create a combination of unique parent + child locator to create a resultant required unique xpath.

Below mentioned is required xpath for clock symbol corresponding to end time which will be unique on entire page-
//input[@id='end_time']/../span/button/i[@class='fa fa-clock-o']

Note:- If you have multiple such buttons, you can make this locator dynamic instead of creating redundant xpaths.

Comment: I can see the same company linked in almost every answer you posted. How is this relevant to this and other answers?